# Parse td Element With BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to grab the "Last Light" time from [this link](https://www.surfline.com/surf-report/terra-mar-point/5842041f4e65fad6a77088a6) using BeautifulSoup. Here is an image of the exact `td` element I need:
[image]

Here is what I have so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests

url_page = requests.get("https://www.surfline.com/surf-report/terra-mar-point/5842041f4e65fad6a77088a6")
url_soup = soup(url_page.text, "html.parser")
last_light = url_soup.find("div", {"class": "quiver-forecast-graphs__weather"})
```

I've been having a hard time parsing through `last_light` to find the td element that I need. There has to be an easier way to do this.

Would greatly appreciate anyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

The data you see on the page is loaded from external URL via JavaScript. You can use this script to load the sunlight times for the spot:

```
import json
import datetime
import requests

url = 'https://www.surfline.com/surf-report/terra-mar-point/5842041f4e65fad6a77088a6'
spot_id = url.split('/')[-1]
api_url = 'https://services.surfline.com/kbyg/spots/forecasts/weather?spotId={}&days=6&intervalHours=1'.format(spot_id)
data = requests.get(api_url).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

utc_offset = datetime.timedelta(hours=data['associated']['utcOffset'])
for t in data['data']['sunlightTimes']:
    for k, v in t.items():
        value = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(v) + utc_offset
        print(f"{k:<10}: {value:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}")
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
midnight  : 2020-09-15 00:00:00
dawn      : 2020-09-15 06:09:47
sunrise   : 2020-09-15 06:34:35
sunset    : 2020-09-15 18:56:56
dusk      : 2020-09-15 19:21:44
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
midnight  : 2020-09-16 00:00:00
dawn      : 2020-09-16 06:10:27
sunrise   : 2020-09-16 06:35:14
sunset    : 2020-09-16 18:55:33
dusk      : 2020-09-16 19:20:20
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
midnight  : 2020-09-17 00:00:00
dawn      : 2020-09-17 06:11:06
sunrise   : 2020-09-17 06:35:52
sunset    : 2020-09-17 18:54:10
dusk      : 2020-09-17 19:18:56
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
midnight  : 2020-09-18 00:00:00
dawn      : 2020-09-18 06:11:46
sunrise   : 2020-09-18 06:36:31
sunset    : 2020-09-18 18:52:47
dusk      : 2020-09-18 19:17:32
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
midnight  : 2020-09-19 00:00:00
dawn      : 2020-09-19 06:12:26
sunrise   : 2020-09-19 06:37:10
sunset    : 2020-09-19 18:51:24
dusk      : 2020-09-19 19:16:08
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
midnight  : 2020-09-20 00:00:00
dawn      : 2020-09-20 06:13:05
sunrise   : 2020-09-20 06:37:48
sunset    : 2020-09-20 18:50:01
dusk      : 2020-09-20 19:14:44
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Do you know how to get just the "Last Light" number (highlighted in the above photo)?

Comment: @ColeStriler I think this is the `"dusk"` key, so probably `data['data']['sunlightTimes'][0]["dusk"]` contains your time.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you!